# OP_READ only ready when SocketChannel.write() completes?

Tags: java, nio

Say I have ONE SocketChannel on a server waiting for OP_READ to become ready and ONE SocketChannel on a client that uses ONE write call on a buffer to send data to the server. Is it then guaranteed that OP_READ will only be ready once ALL data that the client sent has arrived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it then guaranteed that OP_READ will only be ready once ALL data that the client sent has arrived?

Short answer: no.

Long answer:

The receiving channel will become ready as soon as at least one byte is available to read.  Bytes will typically become available more than one at a time, but in general, there is no guarantee how the overall buffer-full of bytes will be split up, and certainly none that all bytes will arrive before the receiving channel signals readiness.  The data may be split up at multiple points on both the writing side and the reading side.  This has little to do with number of senders, number of receivers, or resource contention.

The details depend to some extent on the underlying network protocol -- for example, pretty much all bets are off for a stream-type protocol such as TCP, but a datagram-type protocol such as UDP should give you the kind of all-at-once behavior you seem to want.  UDP in particular, however, does not offer guaranteed delivery, so you have different issues to deal with in that case.  The channel abstraction is a better fit to a stream-type protocol.